# Sed replace path for directory from special file with delimirers slash

Tags: bash, shell, regex, sed, regular-expressions

i should change on parameter to other from template file in linux.

```
sed -e "s/\${dir}/<in this place i should input path, like /home/username>/" /etc/nginx/site.conf
```

But it does not work. How to resolve it ? May be there are other ways, how to resolve it ?
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not tell us what error you got when executing this command. I can see that you are trying to replace some value with a file path containing slashes. You need to either escape the slashes `\/` of file path or use another form of `sed` delimiters like this:

```
sed -e 's|\${dir}|/home/username>|' /etc/nginx/site.conf
```

Please, note that this command will not change the input file. It will show the modified output to stdout. Use `-i` option to update the file in-place or redirect output to another file.

Comment: why i can't user standart stdout ? like this sed -e 's|\${dir}|/home/username>|' /etc/nginx/site.conf > /root/test.conf

Comment: if i want to read from one template file, and write to other ?

Comment: @Piduna: Use sed command with redirect `>` to write to another file.

Comment: yes, but if i start it in a loop, where i have several usernames. i have only first username in all files